# Reference ID not updated with Doctrine association

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, associations

There is probably something I did understand with Doctrine association.

I have a first class :

```
  class FitComments
  {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="SEQ_FIT_COMMENTS", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FitCommentsId",mappedBy="comments",cascade={"persist"})
     * 
     */
    private $elements;


    /****/
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->elements=new ArrayCollection();
    }
    public function getElements()
    {
       return $this->elements;
    }
   ....
  }
```

And a another Class, the list of elements ID that the comments is link.

```
/**
 * FitCommentsId
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class FitCommentsId
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="SEQ_FIT_COMMENTS_ID", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FitComments",inversedBy="elements")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="COMMENTS_ID",referencedColumnName="ID")
     */
    private $comments;

   ....
}
```

I use :

```
  $comments=new FitComment();
  $commentId=new FitCommentId();
  ....
  $comments->getElements()->add($commentId);
  ....
  $entityManager->persist($comment);
  $entityManager->flush();
```

But I have a error. $commentId->comments is null. It must be filled with $comment->id normally.

If I must filled manually $commentId->comments, association is not very usefull.

Perhaps I don't understand mechanism.

Note : the SGDB is Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Try persisting the $commentId also like this:

```
$comment = new FitComment();
$commentId = new FitCommentId();
....
$comment->getElements()->add($commentId);
....
$entityManager->persist($commentId);
$entityManager->persist($comment);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

No I can't do a 'persist' to $commentId first, because 'persist' to $comment class initiate Oracle sequence for the Id of $comments. (I'm not sure it's very clean what I say....)

'commentID->comments' is link to 'comment->id', and is not null.

I must create $comment at first, and after, create the $commentId.

I know that Doctrine use Sequence before saving record, in persist command. Perhaps I can do a persist without flush at first, and at the end of $commentId recording, do a flush.